# Convert words to links and replace them in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, loops, dynamic

I have a string containing names which could be dynamic(1 or more).....i want to convert those names to hyperlinks...and those hyperlinks will contain those names ..

eg. In string "john,jim,jean".....john will be hyperlinked and redirects to "www.abc.com/john" and so on......

I have already accessed the elements by jquery using....as the are inside elements i used `.children().text()` the split and save them in `regs[]`

```
<label>Ids: <span> john,jim,jean</span></label>
```

```
var strr=$('label:contains("IDs:")').children().text();

var regs = strr.split(",") 
var reg_length = regs.length;
```

I dont want to change the text in html, just want to convert them in hyperlinks.

like when click on `john` will redirect to`www.abc.com/john` and so on the others name.

without changing the visible string `john,jim,jean`

Comment: Two things I don't get: "will contain those names numbers" - what are names numbers? "I dont want to change the text in html, just want to convert them in hyperlinks" - and then in the next line you do convert the text to html (how else would you add a link)

Comment: Also, your label content says "Ids" (small "d") and your selector is looking for "IDs" (capital "D")

Comment: hi @Connum ...sorry.....got it right this time please read again......and dont bother about D its corrected in the main code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for

```js
let spanDom = $("label").find("span");
let str = $(spanDom).text().trim();

let s = str.split(",");

$(spanDom).empty();

s.forEach(function( name ) {
  $(spanDom).append("<a href='www.abc.com/"+name+"'>"+name+"</a>,");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Ids: <span> john,jim,jean</span></label>
```

Answer (score 5):

i see you used jquery, so i will also

```
regs = regs.map( s => $(`<a href='www.abc.com/${s}'>${s}</a>`) )
```

uses [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create the elements from each item of the array, with the help of [string templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and jquery.

Comment: Wonderful solution, kudos to you

Answer (score 1):

try

```js
let w = ["john", "jim", "jean" ];  // list of known words to link

data.innerHTML = data.innerHTML.replace(/\w+/g, 
  x=> w.includes(x) ? `<a href="www.abc.com/${x}">${x}</a>` : x)
```

```html
<label id='data'>Ids: <span> john,jim,jean</span></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is totally achievable provided your strings follow a common separation pattern like a comma (,) or a space.  I'll assume that your names in the string are separated by commas and spaces `", "` I'll show it without jQuery.
Firstly the `<span>` element containing the string needs to have an ID. Also, I'm adding a `<p>` as a placeholder for the hyperlinks.

```
<span id="names">John, Jim, Jean </span>
<p id="hps"></p>
```

Now the JavaScript:

```
nameString = document.getElementById("names").innerHTML; //get the string from <span>

nameArray = nameString.split(", "); 
//This method will take the string and break it down wherever it finds the occurrence of the argument (here ", ") and remove these characters and the individual broken down strings are returned as an array 
//nameArray has all the names stored in an array
//Let's create an array links that will hold all your <a> elements
links = new Array();
len = nameArray.length; //Get the length of the array i.e. number of names
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   links[i] = document.createElement("a"); //create an <a> tag
   links[i].setAttribute("href", "www.abc.com/"+nameArray[i]); //Set its href
   links[i].innerHTML = nameArray[i]; //Add Link names i.e. contents inside <a></a>
   document.getElementById("hps").appendChild(links[i]); //append these links as childs to the <p> parent tag
}
```